# University e-learning platform using Tin Can API and an LRS

Tags: html, tin-can-api

I have a project where I aim to create a cross platform e-learning experience for my university.
I plan to create it using HTML 5 and implement Tin Can/ Experience API but as it is relatively new I am unsure how to go about doing this.

My end product will rely heavily on gamification and utilise interactive learning games (Flash), a leader board system and individual student profiles. I am aware Tin can requires an LRS but as this is my first time creating an e learning product, finding a starting point seems to be proving difficult.

Where do I start in regards to an LRS or Tin Can and is this even the best solution to the project?

Any tutorial links and guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe, Tin Can does seem like the most appropriate e-learning standard for your solution.

In terms of getting started, probably the best thing to do is register for a free LRS account somewhere like [SCORM Cloud](http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-cloud-features/tin-can-api-scorm-cloud/?utm_source=tincanapi_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=tin_can_scorm_cloud?pmc=em-1) and take a look at the prototypes at [http://tincanapi.com/prototypes/](http://tincanapi.com/prototypes/?utm_source=tincanapi_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=prototypes?pmc=em-1), especially the Tetris example, and the code libraries on the same site (I'm only allowed by Stack Overflow to post 2 links)

Due to the large effort involved, I don't recommend that you attempt to build an LRS, but rather that you build a solution that will interoperate with any standards compliant LRS. I think that will give you a nicer solution for a University project too.